# rxjs conditional observable on reactive form valueChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable that watches for a value change on a reactive form and then qets a new query based on the value change

```
// this need to run like this...on accountId.value changes if id is > 0 , otherwise accountMessagesDataSource$ = []
this.accountMessagesDataSource$ = this.piForm.get('accountId').valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap(query => this.pitching.getAccountMessage(query)),
    tap(accountMessages => this.accountMessages = accountMessages)).subscribe();
```

I need so run this conditionally as described in the comment line above...

Comment: what is the purpose of accountMessagesDataSource$ ? is the source of data in your template or just the Subscription holder?

Comment: it's the data source for a typeahead in the template using the async pipe

Comment: is the data source don t  subscribe in the component, let the template handle the subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to run `getAccountMessage` only when `id > 0` and otherwise just return an empty array:

```
this.accountMessagesDataSource$ = this.piForm.get('accountId').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    switchMap(id => id > 0
      ? this.pitching.getAccountMessage(id)
      : of([])
    ),
    tap(accountMessages => this.accountMessages = accountMessages),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: thanks so much...I get this error..
`ERROR in src/app/modules/ui/components/pi-form/pi-form.component.ts(99,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'of'.
src/app/modules/ui/components/pi-form/pi-form.component.ts(101,32): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
src/app/modules/ui/components/pi-form/pi-form.component.ts(101,32): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.`
What am I missing?

Comment: you need to import `of()` with `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

Answer (score 0):

you can use flatMap to compose your stream

```
this.accountMessagesDataSource$ = this.piForm.get('accountId').valueChanges.flatMap((id)=> id > 0 ? this.pitching.getAccountMessage(id):of([]))
```